# Syncing iPhone on Banshee

Tags: 11.10, banshee, iphone

On a previous question I have been told to use Banshee as a replacement for iTunes, which leads me to this question:can I upload movies on my iPhone using Banshee instead of iTunes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Banshee is more than capable of syncing content from your library to your iPhone however it depends on the model of iPhone and the software version installed on it.

The current version of `gtkpod` does not support the iPhone 4 (and essentially iOS 5) see the SourceForge [release notes here](http://gtkpod.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=gtkpod/libgpod;a=blob;f=NEWS;h=def943e094b551ba90ff565a866b1cc0ac648407;hb=HEAD)

Answer (score 0):

Banshee does work.
However it crashes sometimes.
The best way to work around the crashes is to connect the iphone, it mounts, and then go in the iphone folders to **Itunes_Control/iTunes/**. 
Rename the file **Playcounts.plist** as Playcounts.plist.txt. Then start Banshee.
And all works.
This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/1313430).